# Why isn't CodeIgniter taking certain variables as the third argument to form_dropdown()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My form is set up to load values from a database (which I've passed via the template engine) on first load, and from POSTed values on subsequent loads if a validation fails. For instance, things like this work fine:

```
 $title = array(
              'name'        => 'aboutme',
              'id'          => 'aboutme',
              'value'       => set_value('aboutme','{about_me}'),
              'rows'        => '20',
              'cols'        => '64'
            );
```

But I'm stumbling on form_dropdown.

```
$ethnicity_array = array('Please choose', 'Asian', 'Black', 'Hispanic / Latin',  'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'Southeast Asian', 'White', 'Mixed', 'Other');

echo form_dropdown('ethnicity', $ethnicity_array,set_value('ethnicity','{ethnicity}'));
```

It doesn't generate the HTML to mark a choice as selected.

Even this fails:

```
$var = set_value('ethnicity','{ethnicity}');

echo $var;     // verify that it has the expected value, let's say 7

echo form_dropdown('ethnicity', $ethnicity_array,$var);
```

This also fails -- that is, it doesn't generate the proper HTML to mark the corresponding option as selected:

```
echo form_dropdown('ethnicity',$ethnicity_array,(isset($_POST['ethnicity']) ? $_POST['ethnicity'] : $var));
```

But, THIS works:

```
echo form_dropdown('ethnicity', $ethnicity_array,7);
```

And this:

```
$var = 7;

echo form_dropdown('ethnicity', $ethnicity_array,$var);
```

It seems like it's some sort of type casting issue, so maybe it's just something I fundamentally don't understand about PHP.

Update: it may be a typecasting issue. Trying this:

```
$var = "{ethnicity}";

echo var_dump($var);

$iv = intval($var);

echo "<div>IV:</div>";

echo var_dump($iv);
```

Yields:

string(15) "7"
IV:
int(0)

I have no clue why intval() is return 0 for the string "7". I've looked at other questions about intval() here on stackoverflow and now I'm even more confused. But if form_dropdown is also trying an int conversion and it's failing, that might be the problem.

Comment: had you tried with array for set_value

Comment: where is your `$ethnicity_array`??

Comment: $ethnicity_array is immediately preceding the code. I've updated the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the `set_value` as the third paramenter
your code should be like this

```
echo form_dropdown('ethnicity', $ethnicity_array, set_value('ethnicity'));
```